# How do I insert the immediate inserted row's column to the next column in bulk insert?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
    (
      Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      Amount MONEY ,
      Rate FLOAT ,
      NetAmount MONEY
    );
CREATE TABLE #rate ( Rate FLOAT );
INSERT  INTO #rate
        ( Rate )
VALUES  ( 1.2 );
  -- Rate - float

INSERT  INTO #rate
        ( Rate )
VALUES  ( 1.3  -- Rate - float
          );

INSERT  INTO #rate
        ( Rate )
VALUES  ( 1.5  -- Rate - float
          );
DECLARE @Amount MONEY = 5000;
INSERT  INTO #tmp
        ( Amount ,
          Rate ,
          NetAmount
        ) 
        SELECT  @Amount ,
                r.Rate ,
                r.Rate * @Amount
        FROM    #rate AS r;


SELECT  *
FROM    #tmp AS t;

DROP TABLE #rate;
DROP TABLE #tmp;
```

This is my Output:

```
Id          Amount                Rate                   NetAmount
----------- --------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------
1           5000.00               1.2                    6000.00
2           5000.00               1.3                    6500.00
3           5000.00               1.5                    7500.00
```

I  need output like  this :

```
Id          Amount                Rate                   NetAmount
    ----------- --------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------
    1           5000.00               1.2                    6000.00
    2           6000.00               1.3                    7800.00
    3           7800.00               1.5                    11700.00
```

As you can see the first amount 5000.00 is received as a parameter and then there is a list of defined rates which is in a particular order. I need to multiply every rates as you can see in my required output. The first NetAmount becomes Amount for the next row.

I want to achieve this preferably without using cursor or while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just add [Computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table) and see the magic in output as

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
    (
      Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      Amount MONEY ,
      Rate FLOAT ,
      NetAmount AS Amount * Rate    -- computed column 
    );
CREATE TABLE #rate ( Rate FLOAT );
INSERT  INTO #rate
        ( Rate )
VALUES  ( 1.2 );
  -- Rate - float

INSERT  INTO #rate
        ( Rate )
VALUES  ( 1.3  -- Rate - float
          );

INSERT  INTO #rate
        ( Rate )
VALUES  ( 1.5  -- Rate - float
          );
DECLARE @Amount MONEY = 5000;
INSERT  INTO #tmp
        ( Amount ,
          Rate
          --, NetAmount
        ) 
        SELECT  @Amount ,
                r.Rate 
                --,r.Rate * @Amount
        FROM    #rate AS r;


SELECT  *
FROM    #tmp AS t;

DROP TABLE #rate;
DROP TABLE #tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a cumulative product of rate for this. However, there is no built in function to achieve that. You can achieve this using [`LOG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/log-transact-sql) and [`EXP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/exp-transact-sql) in conjunction with cumulative `SUM`:

```
insert into #tmp (amount, rate, netamount)
select lag(netamount, 1, @Amount) over (order by id) as amount,
    rate,
    netamount
from (
    select id,
        @amount * exp(sum(log(rate)) over (order by id)) as netamount,
        rate
    from #rate
    ) t;
```

This assumes that you have an ID column in the rate table, on order of which you'd like the rate applied and amount calculated. *Remember*, there is no intrinsic order in RDBMS.